# AWS - SNS (India Text Message) Not sending via Local Routes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

Am Using the Java API to try to send SMS to India Numbers.
I have a valid Entity ID and Template ID registered using JIO DLT (https://trueconnect.jio.com/#/)

I am setting Messaage Attributes as following

```
AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType - Transactional
AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID - <My Registered Sender ID>
AWS.MM.SMS.EntityId - <DLT provided Entity ID>
AWS.MM.SMS.TemplateId - <Template ID of the message i want to send>
```

Am using *`software.amazon.awssdk.services.sns.SnsClient`* to send the Request as below...

```
PublishRequest pb = PublishRequest.builder()
    .message(message)
    .phoneNumber(snsDefaultCountryCode+to)
    .messageAttributes(smsAttributes).build();
                
PublishResponse result = snsClient.publish(pb);
```

I do receive the SMS, but via ILDO with international charges. I was expecting the message to go via local routes or at least a response with error 'Entity ID is invalid' or 'Template ID is invalid' etc.

Are there any other steps to do before sending SMS to india using the AWS services?

Comment: Amazon SNS does not support Jio DLT we also trying to do the same but unable to register our Sender ID and template id with them.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to register the DLT sender id with AWS using a service limit support request on Pinpoint SMS Service.

After AWS support team approves your request, which may take upto 24 hours your SMS will get routed via India with sender id

[Please find the reference link for the same here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/channels-sms-awssupport-sender-id.html#channels-sms-awssupport-sender-id-open)